# Use a Single VPS for Multiple Customers

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, vps, shared-hosting

I run a small web development and design business and also offer hosting to my clients.

So far, I've been buying very affordable VPS' and using those for my customers. Since many of my customers have small WordPress websites or static websites with no database, I can put 5-10 customers on a single VPS.

The problem is that I don't offer cpanel or any other administrative panel since that would be too expensive. I create an SSH account for each customer with access only to their folder.

All VPS' run Ubuntu and either Apache or nginx. I use Apache or nginx virtual hosts to point each domain to the corresponding folder.

The process is a little time consuming since every time I have a new client I have to manually create a new SSH user and grant him access to a particular folder.

Is this approach bad or not recommended? Is there a better way for me to handle this? Is there a better way to share a VPS with multiple clients?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Creating a user and granting access to a folder should take a few seconds. I'm confused - it seems like you're overcomplicating this? If the process is time consuming, consider automating it with something like Ansible.

Comment: Free control panels like virtualmin could help.

Comment: @billc.cn Control panels make virtually everything about properly managing a server more difficult. Questions about them are explicitly off-topic on ServerFault for this exact reason.

Answer (score 1):

There's always a better way, one of them being ansible.

Simply make a few roles (nginx, apache, mysql, common) and migrate your manual tasks to playbooks, each time you add a user  (which could be to an internal billing system) you would rerun your playbook to add them to your VPS of choice.